# And Or Conditions

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I currently have a rather large conditional:

```
a[i1][i2 + 1] == '1' || a[i1][i2 - 1] == '1' || a[i1 + 1][i2] == '1' || a[i1 - 1][i2] == '1'
```

This works great however I just realised this is only half of what I need. Basically I need at least two of those conditionals to be `true`. **Is there an easy way to accomplish this or do I have to rewrite the whole thing as needed?**

An easy way to showcase what I mean is by the following.

Say I have three conditionals: a, b, and c. What I need in short is `(a&&b) || (a&&c) || (b&&c)`

Comment: And did you try it to see if it works ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. Do you want to simplify the expression? You could do `a && (b || c) || b && c`. Other than that, instead of recomputing `a[i1][i2 + 1] == '1'` multiple times in the condition, just do it once and assign the value to a variable.

Comment: I see your values are compared to '1' what are the other possible values ?

Comment: @aduch Because I'm comparing between 1 & 0 and because I only need 1, it is my only value.

Comment: Then check Özgür Kaplan's answer below I think it's nice

Comment: I decided to use @FelixKling's method of `a && (b || c) || b && c` as it makes the most sense to me and even when you have a lot of conditionals it remains reasonably small. Create this as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this.

```
var numberOfTrue=Number(a[i1][i2 + 1] == '1')+ Number(a[i1][i2 - 1] == '1'); // +....
if(numberOfTrue>=2){
//TODO
}
```

http://jsbin.com/wasuwoxe/1/edit

Comment: That was the one I had in mind, but this works only if the other possible value is '0' or 0

Comment: Which seems to be the case, +1

Answer (score 1):

Since true+true+false === 2, you can simply say:

```
   ((a[i1][i2 + 1] == '1') +
    (a[i1][i2 - 1] == '1') +
    (a[i1 + 1][i2] == '1') +
    (a[i1 - 1][i2] == '1'_) >= 2
```

Comment: Isn't this just what @ÖzgürKaplan did just formatted differently?

Comment: Yes, it's the same idea. But the Number(..) wrapper is not needed so I think this answer looks neater.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to utilize an Array to store the matched conditions. This way you can still define what evaluates to `true` and use the Array to store which conditions matched and view it afterwards.

```
var matched = [];

if (a[i1][i2 + 1] == '1') matched.push({x: i1, y: i2 + 1});
if (a[i1][i2 - 1] == '1') matched.push({x: i1, y: i2 - 1});
if (a[i1 + 1][i2] == '1') matched.push({x: i1 + 1, y: i2});
if (a[i1 - 1][i2] == '1') matched.push({x: i1 - 1, y: i2});

if (matched.length >= 2) {
    console.log('These matched!', matched);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this?

```
var o = i1 + 1;
var p = i1 - 1;
var q = i2 + 1;
var r = i2 -1;
a[i1][q] == '1' || a[i1][r] == '1' || a[o][i2] == '1' || a[p][i2] == '1'
```

or something like this:

```
var a; // you should init this array in somewhere else above

function isValid(i1, i2){

return (a[i1][i2 + 1] == '1' || a[i1][i2 - 1] == '1' || a[i1 + 1][i2] == '1' || a[i1 - 1][i2] == '1')
}
```